# Algorithm for top K stock in electronic exchange

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hash, tree, heap

You work in an electronic exchange. Throughout the day, you receive ticks (trading data) which consists of product name and its traded volume of stocks. Eg: `{name: vodafone, volume: 20}`

What data structure will you maintain if:

- You have to tell top `k` products traded by volume at end of day.
- You have to tell top `k` products traded by volume throughout the day.

What's the most efficient solution that you can think of?

The most efficient solution I could think of was to use a heap and map for both situations

- heap to store stock by decreasing volume (updating - `O(logn)`and  getTop k - `O(k)`)
- map to track stock volume  (updating - `O(1)`)

Comment: You have mentioned few data structures but what if on a daily basis the volume of all the stocks is too damn high that it causes heap to cause memory overflow. Think around that part as well.

Comment: Are the total volumes cumulative, or do you receive each product name just once during the day? Is `k` known in advance, or do you have to answer queries with various values of `k`?

Comment: @kaya3 total volumes are cumulative - so you may receive the same product multiple times, and the value of ```k``` is variable

Comment: OK, and how are you getting the top k in O(1) time? It takes O(*k*) time just to output *k* things.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant o(k)

Comment: It's also not clear how you're doing updates in a heap in O(log *n*) time; when a query comes in, you don't know where that company is in the heap.

Comment: delete takes O(logn) + insert O(logn) - so overall is O(logn), or use a map to store the location so delete becomes O(1) + O(logn) = O(logn)

Comment: Deleting the minimum from a heap takes O(log *n*) time, but deleting an arbitrary element doesn't if you don't already know which index that element is stored at. Yes, you can use the map to store the current location, but that wasn't stated in your question; if you do that, deletion is still O(log *n*), though, not O(1).

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Comment: Most efficient? What is efficient enough? How deep are your pockets? Big O gives no indication of constants, and so means little without appropriate tests. Can you afford the memory? The maintenance?

Comment: @zenwraight the number of different companies that are traded on one exchange is going to be a few thousand; certainly small enough to fit in memory.

Comment: It looks as if collections.Counter could give the correct results. You might want to test that and look for actual bottlenecks in the encompassing process flow caused by this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is a kind of map or dictionary which supports the following queries:

- `Add(key, x)`: add x to the total for that key, creating a new entry if it doesn't already exist.
- `GetKLargest(k)`: return the keys/totals for the k largest entries.

Let's say *Q* is the number of queries, and *n* is the number of distinct keys. We should assume that *Q* is much larger than *n*; choosing the NYSE as an example, there are a few thousand stocks traded, and a few million trades per day.

---

In the first scenario we assume that there are a large number of `Add` queries followed by one `GetKLargest` query. Since the cost of the `Add` query dominates, we can use a [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable) so that `Add` takes O(1) time, and then at the end of the day we can do `GetKLargest` in O(*n* log *k*) time using a priority queue of size *k*; note that we don't need to sort the whole key-set in O(*n* log *n*) time just to find the *k* largest elements. The total cost of answering *Q* queries is O(*Q* + *n* log *k*).

---

In the second scenario, we assume there could be a large number of both kinds of query. The cost of either query could dominate. A good option is to use an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), which supports `Add` in O(log *n*) time, and `GetKLargest` in O(*k* log *n*) time. To look up a company by name in the tree requires a separate index, which can be maintained as a hashtable. The total cost is O(*Qk* log *n*) in the worst case.

---

If *k* is fixed or has a fixed limit, we can do better: keep the totals in a hashtable, but also maintain a priority queue of the current top *k* elements alongside. The cost of the `Add` query is now O(log *k*) because of maintaining the priority queue; to do this efficiently we need the map to also store the current index of each company in the priority queue, if it's there, otherwise searching the priority queue for the right company is O(*k*). The cost of `GetKLargest` is O(*k*) since we just output the contents of the priority queue. (The problem doesn't say we need to output them in order. If we do, then we can use a sorted array instead of a heap for the priority queue, and `Add` takes O(*k*) time.)

In this case, the total cost of answering *Q* queries is O(*Qk*). Note that this only works if we know in advance the maximum value of *k* that could be queried, before the query arrives; otherwise we don't know how big to make the priority queue.

Comment: for the second scenario when `k` is variable - how is using an ```order statistic tree``` better than using a ```max-heap``` when both take O(logn) for updates?

Comment: A max heap cannot be used as a map/dictionary. You cannot look up a company by name in O(log *n*) time. You also cannot poll the largest *k* entries from a heap in only O(*k*) time.

Comment: It seems to me that in both second and third cases we can use ordinary binary search tree to store (aggregated volume, name) pairs. In `Add` operation we lookup current aggregated volume in hashtable, remove corresponding pair from a BST, insert a new pair back with updated volume in O(log(size(BST)) and update aggregated volume in hashtable. In `GetKLargest` we traverse k elements of BST in-order in O(k).

Comment: @LeonidVasilev Yes, looking back now, there is no need for an order statistic tree (though it is just a BST where each node also knows its subtree's cardinality, so it doesn't cost anything asymptotically to use one instead of a BST). You can get the k largest elements from any balanced BST by in-order traversal. That said, it's not O(k) time to do this, because e.g. in the case k=1 you can't get the smallest element (which in general could be a leaf) without descending the whole tree in O(log n) time. It might be O(k + log n) instead of O(k log n), but I can't find a source to confirm.